# ProgramData folder cannot access after another process (updater.exe) access it

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an exe runs in **C:\ProgramFiles\MyAPP\MyApplication.exe** and this app runs at startup
`(HKLM: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)` The SQLite database and other configuration files located at **C:\ProgramData\MyAppSettings** Folder

I’m installing the application using `Inno Setup` and I have set **ProgramData\MyAppSettings** folder permission to `users-full` by using this code snippet.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{commonappdata}\MyAppSettings"; Permissions: users-modify users-full
```

I have a **updater.exe** too which downloads the latest updates (as 2 zip files) and extracts them to **Program Files** and **ProgramData** folders.

The workflow of this update process is like this.

1. **MyApplication.exe** starts at windows start.
2. User Login into the **MyApplication**.
3. Show *Updates Available* window and the User clicks on the *update now* button.
4. Prompt `UAC` and Launch **updater.exe** as Administrator. Then terminate the **MyApplication.exe**
5. The **updater.exe** will download zip files and extract them to correct folders.
6. Then the updater will start **MyApplication.exe**  again and terminate themself.

All those things work fine except one thing.

After **updater.exe** extract, the zip file on `ProgramData` the **MyApplication.exe** cannot access files on it

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\MyAppSettings\Database.db' is denied.`

So I have tried something like this.
Before the **updater.exe** terminate, it grant access permission to `Everyone` `Full Control`

```
Private Sub GrantAccessPermission(ByVal fullPath As String)
        Dim dInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(fullPath)
        Dim dSecurity As DirectorySecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl()
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow))
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity)
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same. **MyApplication.exe** still cannot access files in the `ProgramData`. Where could the problem be?

Folder and database file permission

[image]
[image]

what **updater.exe** doing in the `ProgramData` folder

```
Using Zip As New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile(BaseCompSource)
   Dim Entry As ZipEntry
   For Each Entry In Zip
      Try

         Entry.ExtractWithPassword(BaseCompDestination, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently, Password)
         setTaskText(Entry.FileName)

      Catch ex As Exception
         Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
      End Try

   Next
End Using
```

Comment: What are the permissions on C:\ProgramData\MyAppSettings\Database.db before and after the update? Is MyApplication.exe trying to access the file before updater.exe has released it?

Comment: Folders or Files created in ProgramData usually inherit `Everyone - Full Control` permission from the Parent Folder. You could describe what the Updater is doing, possibly in code.

Comment: @AndrewMorton before i tried `GrantAccessPermission` the permission is not changed at all. after `GrantAccessPermission` it adds `Everyone` in the list and set all permission on it except special permission (i will add screenshots) After update i have tired lot of time by running `MyApplication.exe` (by double clicking on the exe) to test permission issue. and i have makes sure to keep updater.exe not runs in background.

Comment: @Jimi only extact a zip file, I will update the code

Comment: You could find out if some other process has a handle on the file: [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/117902/272824).

Answer (score 0):

I still tying to understand the reason why this happen, but I've found a solution,

After **updater.exe** done update process, I need to set all files and folders in **ProgramData\MyAppSettings** to `NORMAL` attribute at the **MyApplication.exe** first launch (first launch after update)

```
File.SetAttributes(sFile.FullName, FileAttributes.Normal)
MyDirectory.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory
```

then I can hide them back (if only I want)

```
File.SetAttributes(sFile.FullName, File.GetAttributes(sFile.FullName) Or FileAttributes.Hidden Or FileAttributes.System)
MyDirectory.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory Or FileAttributes.Hidden Or FileAttributes.System
```

Now the exception doesn't shows up.